# How to disable ng-template-loader from looking at image src's?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack

I am starting to use `webpack` as my build tool for an `angular` project.  I am having to pull in `ng-template-loader` to create my `templateCache`.  Here is my `webpack` config:

```
{
  test: /\.html$/,
  loader: 'ngtemplate!html'
}
```

And now I can import my `html` files like this

```
var template = require('./menu.html');
```

This works fine, but in my `html`, I have an `<img />` with a `src` that points to a source that doesn't exist in my dev environment.  It keeps breaking, saying

`Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory'`

How do I get around this, or disable it so I can build my project?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

`ngtemplate-loader` uses `html-loader` so you can pass the attrs property in as follows, in order to disable default attribute handling:

```
{
    test: /\.html$/,
    loader: 'ngtemplate!html?attrs=false'
}
```